# Listagg syntax in Oracle 10, 11

Tags: oracle

I have a simple program:

```
Select 
Soccer||', ' ||football  as test,
ID
From sport
Where ID = 123
```

Here is the result from query above:

```
Test       ID
Adis, Nike 123
,          123
```

How do I edit my code below to remove the comma "," such that it only displays one row?

```
Select
LISTING (a.test, ', ') within group (order by a.test) as equipment,
ID
From
    (
     Select
     soccer||', '||football as test,
     ID
     From test
     where ID =123
    )a
Group by I'd
```

The result shows

```
Equipment       ID
, , Adis, Nike  123
```

My desired result:

```
Equipment  ID
Adis, Nike 123
```

I am running Oracle 11.

Comment: Why does the title mention Oracle 10? From the output you have two rows, one with both columns set, and the other with them both null. What do you want to do if you have rows with only one value set? Maybe you can add some more realistic/varied data and the result you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `listagg` is aggregating the existing concatenated results from the two rows, `'Adis, Nike'` and `', '`, as a list with another comma between them. The concatenation probably isn't what you really want; though you could make it skip the comma if there is only one value:

```
select soccer
  || case when soccer is not null and football is not null then ', ' end
  || football as test, id
from sport
where id = 123;

TEST                           ID
---------------------- ----------
Adis, Nike                    123
                              123
```

And then exclude any null values in your outer `listagg`:

```
select listagg (equipment, ', ') within group (order by equipment) as equipment, id
from (
  select soccer
    || case when soccer is not null and football is not null then ', ' end
    || football as equipment, id
  from sport
  where id = 123
)
where id = 123
and equipment is not null
group by id;

EQUIPMENT                              ID
------------------------------ ----------
Adis, Nike                            123
```

You could also use a `union` to convert the columns into separate rows (a kind of manual unpivot):

```
select id, soccer as equipment from sport
union all
select id, football as equipment from sport;

        ID EQUIPMENT                    
---------- ------------------------------
       123 Adis                          
       123                               
       123 Nike                          
       123
```

And then use that as an inline view, aggregating the list it returns, and excluding the null entries:

```
select listagg (equipment, ', ') within group (order by equipment) as equipment, id
from (
  select id, soccer as equipment from sport
  union all
  select id, football as equipment from sport
)
where id = 123
and equipment is not null
group by id;

EQUIPMENT                              ID
------------------------------ ----------
Adis, Nike                            123
```

Comment: Hi Alex, suppose that I want to add a Simi column (;). The result is: Adis, usa; Nike,  usa.

Comment: @joe - then use the first version, with the case for the comma; and then a semicolon in the listagg?

Comment: Hi Mr. Poole, hope all is well to you. Now, suppose that if I have an extra comma (,) for example Nike, Adis, and my result is Nike, Adis, how would I modify such the result will display Nike, Adis? Instead of Nike, Adis, ?

Comment: @joe - you can use `trim()`to remove the trailing comma (or is it a comma and a space?) but it would be better to avoid having it. I'm not sue why it's there though, is it in the raw data (in the soccer or football column) or just in the result? One issue i can see with my first solution is that the case should probably be: `case when soccer is not null and football is not null then ', ' end` otherwise you'd get a trailing comma if football was null.

Comment: @Mr. Poole, yes it is soccer raw data. And yes it is a comma without a space. Thanks so much for your quick response!